# What keyboard shortcut can I use in the Git terminal to exit out of 'git-diff' without restarting VS Code using 'CMD + Q'?

Tags: git, zsh, git-diff

Good Morning everybody...

Someone may help me to know which git terminal shortcut keybord should i use
to exit git response after a "git diff".

I actually do "CMD + Q", but still have to restart entirely vs code after this.

Not useful at all...

I didn't find anything else to solve my problem.

Thank you !

Have a nice day :-)

Comment: Assuming that you see the default pager, "less", it should be just `q` (the lower-case version of the letter).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+exit+diff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 'q' key (for quit). You use that to exit anything from git.